# Issues when modelling LSTM for multi series

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I'm a beginner on time series analysis with deep learning, and I have been searching for examples with LSTM in which more than one series (for example one for each city or place) is trained to avoid fitting a model for each one. The main benefit of course is that you have more training data and less computational costs. I have found an interesting code to help modeling this problem with conditional/temporally-static variables (it's called [cond-rnn](https://github.com/philipperemy/cond_rnn)). But wherever I search, it's not clear to me some issues regarding sorting the inputs appropriately.

The context is that I have a target and a set of autoregressive inputs (features, lags, timesteps, wherever you call it), in which data from different series are stack together. RF and GB are outperforming LSTM on this task (with overfitting, even when I use 100k+ samples, dropout or regularization), and I'm not sure if I'm using it appropriately.

It is wrong to stack series together and have the inputs-targets randomly sorted (as in the figure)? Does the LSTM need to receive the inputs temporally sorted?

If they need so, do you have any advice on how to deal with the problem of providing new series (that start from the first time period) to the LSTM training? This [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358837/143783) to a similar problem (but another perspective) suggest to pick "places" as an input column, but I don't think this answer help the questions here I posed.

[image]

Comment: I am a little confused by your explanation, but it sounds like you want to condition the output of the model based on some categorical variable (place, agent, etc..).  Every category has a similar timeseries, but you expect a different output distribution depending on the category?  I see 2 methods: model your outputs as a mixture of probabilities (see tensorflow_probability).  The number of mixtures is now a hyperparameter.  Or, as the other answer details, condition your output directly in the model by concatenating the categorical variable in the graph.

Comment: There is no such thing as "wrong", but providing the inputs at random would mess up the temporal information and this is probably valuable information. The performance of the LSTM will most likely be better if the inputs are temporally sorted. Regarding the other concern, do the "places" of the series from your test set match those of the training set? (e.g. are all the "cities" in the test set also in the train set?). If so, using the approach of that answer would make sense.

Comment: @rvinas Yes they are in the test set. So what do you think: if I train one "place" time series temporally sorted (~50 samples) for each batch then LSTM is more likely to perform better? Do you thing the temporal information is messed up if I train 100 stacked time series each one temporally sorted together for each batch?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the first question - when I say temporally sorted I mean within each sample (e.g. sequence of time points). The order of the samples in the batch is not important unless you are using a stateful LSTM.  Regarding the second question, if each sample is temporally sorted, it should be ok - that is what is commonly done in practice.

Comment: It was because I was referring a sample as one data point, not an entire time series, but I got your idea thanks a lot.

Comment: Fantastic! Did it work? Do you have any other questions? I am happy to write an answer

Comment: Yes, go ahead. I just tried to train LSTM and other traditional ml algorithms sorting by ['places', 'time'], the former with batches of 8 series together and it seems that LSTM is better. If I train them without batches and randomly sorted, trad ml is better.